# How to add "like" reaction to chat bubble with Android+Smack+XMPP

Tags: android, ejabberd, smack, prosody-im

In one of my chat app, I would like implement functionality to assign "like" reaction to chat bubble which needs to notify other user like below using

[image: Like Reaction Image]

Is it possible to achieve this without any XMPP server side coding? How to pass custom tag using smack and push message?

Comment: use third party library : https://github.com/yannickl/Reactions

Comment: The solution interests me also

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this can be achieved without coding in server side upto ejabberd 16.06. Construct a Message tag for example

```
<message type="chat"  to="xyz@192.168.3.94" id="aad0a" msgtype="emoji">
<body>Emoji Icon</body>
<active xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates"/>
<request xmlns="urn:xmpp:receipts"/>
</message>
```

When you send emoji, add a custom tag msgtype="emoji" and add emoji link to inside the body and validate receiver end.